# Intercept prior to QueryValue binding in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I was looking to use an `HttpServerFilter` to modify the incoming request prior to the execution of the endpoint method in the controller. In my request, I have `@QueryValue` bindings. It looks like the execution of these bindings occurs before the `HttpServerFilter`, so if I wanted to modify query parameters, I would not be able to do so.

Is there any place I can intercept and modify the request prior to the `@QueryValue` binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved by `HttpServerFilter`, but you should update parameter value in the matched route and not in the request. It is because `RoutingInBoundHandler` at first tries to fulfill the argument requirements of the route and then executes the filter chain. See the example below how to do that:

Filter which calls modify service:

```java
@Filter("/hello/**")
public class ModifyRequestFilter implements HttpServerFilter {
    private final ModifyRequestService service;

    public ModifyRequestFilter(ModifyRequestService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain) {
        return service.modify(request)
                .switchMap(aBoolean -> chain.proceed(request));
    }
}
```

Service that does the modification where is the key code: `((NettyHttpRequest<?>) request).getMatchedRoute().getVariableValues().put("value", "modified in filter");`:

```java
@Singleton
public class ModifyRequestService {
    Flowable<Boolean> modify(HttpRequest<?> request) {
        return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
            ((NettyHttpRequest<?>) request).getMatchedRoute().getVariableValues().put("value", "modified in filter");
            return true;
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @Get("/")
    public String index(@QueryValue String value) {
        return "Hello " + value;
    }
}
```

---

Another option is to use own container class for values you want to modify with own type converter.

For example `CustomValue` class is as value container:

```java
public class CustomValue {
    private String value;

    public CustomValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Here is the registrar for custom value converter which converts `CharSequence` into `CustomValue` instance:

```java
@Singleton
@BootstrapContextCompatible
public class CustomConverterRegistrar implements TypeConverterRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void register(ConversionService<?> conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(CharSequence.class, CustomValue.class, 
            s -> new CustomValue(s + "-updated"));
    }
}
```

And here is an example of the controller:

```java
@Controller("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @Get("/in-query")
    public String inQuery(@QueryValue CustomValue value) {
        return "Hello " + value.getValue();
    }

    @Get("/in-path/{value}")
    public String inPath(CustomValue value) {
        return "Hello " + value.getValue();
    }
}
```

And the curl test with result:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/hello/in-query/?value=test
Hello test-updated
$ curl http://localhost:8080/hello/in-path/testFromPath
Hello testFromPath-updated
```

Comment: A small caveat appears to be that the `matchedRoute` will be `null` if the request matches the wildcard in your `@Filter` but doesn't match a route in your controller.  So in the example above, a request to `/hello/notexist` will trigger the filter but `getMatchedRoute()` will return null and an NPE will result.  For me at least, that caused a loop where the filter kept getting called and failing, but that could be some other difference in my setup.
Either way, checking for `null` would be wise.